# Which collection to use?

Tags: java, collections

What kind of collection should I use if I need to create a collection that will allow me to store books and how many copies there are in circulation (for a library)?
        I would use an ArrayList, but I also want to be able to sort the books by order of issue year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Book Class` with all the `attributes` you have for a `book`. And implement a `Comparable` for that `Book Class` and write sorting logic in there.

Maintain a `List<Book>`, and use `Collections.sort` method, to sort your `List` according to the implemented `Sorting` logic.

**UPDATE: -**

As far as, fast look-up is concerned, a `Map` is always the best bet. And is appropriate to implement a dictionary look-up kind of structure. For that, you would need some attribute that uniquely identifies each book. And then store your book as `Map<String, Book>`, where your `key` might be `id` of type `String`.

Also, in this case, your sorting logic will change a little. Now you would have to sort on the basis of your `Map's value`, i.e. on the basis of `attributes` of `Book`.

Here's a sample code you can make use of. I have just considered sorting on the basis of `id`. You can change the sorting logic as needed: -

```
class Book {
    private int id;
    private String title;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book[Title:" + this.getTitle() + ", Id:" + this.getId() + "]";
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Map<String, Book> map = new HashMap<String, Book>() {
            {
                put("b1", new Book(3, "abc"));
                put("b2", new Book(2, "c"));
            }
        };
        List<Map.Entry<String, Book>> keyList = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Book>>(map.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(keyList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Book>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Book> o1, Map.Entry<String, Book> o2) {
                return o1.getValue().getId() - o2.getValue().getId();
            }
        });


        Map<String, Book> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Book>();
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Book>> it = keyList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<String, Book> entry = it.next();
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT: -**

```
"{b2=Book[Title:c, Id:2], b1=Book[Title:abc, Id:3]}"
```

Comment: I would suspect that a library need O(n) lookup time for a book. List provies O(n)

Comment: @ColinD. Well, for look-up purpose, of course a `Map` will be an ideal data structure to use. But Sorting will require a `List`.

Comment: TreeMaps are sorted. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Comment: @ColinD. Yeah that is sorted on the basis of `Key`. But the sorting criteria here cannot be a `key`. OP wants to sort on the basis of `Issue Year`. Can't be a Key right

Answer (score 0):

java.util.TreeMap can be used to index and sort this kind of requirements.

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html for more details.

You can use your Book object as key mapped to the number of copies as the value.

Comment: TreeMap cannot be used for this requirement. You cannot have `Issue Year` as key for your Map. And TreeMap sorts on `key`.

Comment: You can use The Book as the Key having the Issue Year as one of the fields in it and have the # of copies as the values for each Book.This would match the requirement and will give you flexibility to sort books as need change.

Comment: But then, there is a need to override `HashCode` and `equals` method in Book class, with logic that does not break the contract. Yough job for a beginner. It would be better to have `String` as key in a Map for starting.

Comment: True.Those are other things you need to decide looking at the big picture :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, If the entire purpose of your collection is to store the counts of the books, than a dictionary/map, or whatever java's key-value collection is called.

It would probably have `title` as your key, and the `count` as your value.

Now I suspect that your collection might be a little more complicated than that, so you might want to make a `Book` class which has `Count` as a field, and then I'd probably have a `string` -> `Book` dictionary/map anyway, with the `string` as it's dewy decimal number or some other unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond a simple educational or toy project, you'd want to use a database rather than an in-memory collection.  (Not really an answer, but I think worth stating.)